# How to push an array with a hook on react js?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render an array of value . This is basicaly a to do list and i want to render different value with the button "en cours"

My .map doesn't seems to work and my array just record one value. someone can help me ?

There is also an other problem, when i write on my input my letters just disappeared directly ??

```
function Task() {
  const [task, setTask] = useState("");
  const [encours, setEncours] = useState("");
  let toDo = [];

  const handleInputTask = (e) => {
    setTask(e.target.value);
    setEncours("en cours");
  };

  function AddTask() {
    toDo.push(task);
    console.log(toDo);
  }

  const switchEnCours = () => {
    setEncours("terminé");
  };

  const deleteTask = () => {
    setEncours("supprimée");
  };

 function RenderMesTasks() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={handleInputTask}></input>
        <button onClick={AddTask}>Valider</button>
        <div className="DivColonne">
          <div className="Colonne">
            <h1>Tâche à faire</h1>
            {toDo !== "" && encours === "en cours" ? (
              toDo.map((insertTask) => {
                <div>
                  <p>{insertTask}</p>
                  <button onClick={switchEnCours}>{encours}</button>
                </div>;
              })
            ) : (
              <div></div>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="Colonne">
            <h1>Tâche en cours</h1>
            {encours === "terminé" ? (
              <div>
                {toDo.map((insert) => {
                  return (
                    <div>
                      <p>{insert}</p>
                      <button onClick={deleteTask}>{encours}</button>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div></div>
            )}
          </div>
          <div>
            <h1>Tâches terminées</h1>
            {encours === "supprimée" ? (
              <div>
                <p>{toDo}</p>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div></div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2> Ecrivez une nouvelle tâche</h2>
      <div>
        <RenderMesTasks />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Task;
```

Comment: `addTask` doesn't update the react lifecycle, so there is no re-render. Your follow up issue, is you're not storing the input state so it's not going to show any characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this state variable

```
const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);
```

and then in your `AddTask()`, add this

```
function AddTask() {
   setTodoList([...todoList, task]);
}
```

Comment: thank you now i have my array of todolist but nothing render on my .map 
````

Comment: Instead of `toDo.map` write `todoList.map`

Comment: i did but nothing appeared :O

Answer (score 1):

todos is state:

```
const [todos,setTodos] = useState([]);

const addToDo = (todo) => setTodos([...todos,todo])
```